# Optimization for multicast receiver program

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio, multicast

I am writing a program using boost asio to receive multicase messages from around 30 multicase ip in linux with c++. I am here to seek advances on how to minimize packet drop from my client side during runtime. I have already maximized the NIC receive buffer. I am using a 8 core cpu. I am also wondering will the NIC card create same number of buffer queue to equal to number of sockets in the program? Beside configure the NIC card, could I do something on the linux kernel? Since I believe kernel will do buffer copy from the NIC first before our program copy data from it, right?

```
template<typename msg, int id>
void data_service<msg, id>::on_rt_recv( char* p_raw_packet, int p_length, const boost::system::error_code& error )
{
    if (!error)
    {
        //post to strand and wait to proceed
        processing_strand_.post(boost::bind(&data_service::on_rt_recv_handler, this,
            p_raw_packet,
            p_length));

        //continue to listen as soon as possible
        auto new_buffer = get_new_buffer();
        rt_socket_[p_line]->async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(new_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE_), rt_endpoint_,
            boost::bind(&data_service::on_rt_recv, this,
            new_buffer,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        memory_pool_.free((void*)p_raw_packet);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you've already done a `setsockopt(...SO_RCVBUF...)`? Other than that, you can `recvmmsg` under Linux (note the double m, that's not a typo), which uses fewer syscalls and is presumably faster, too. All you can really do is drain the buffers as data comes in (and, faster than it comes in). You can't obviously influence packet loss that occurs on the "cable" other than by not filling the cable e.g. with TCP, you can only control what's dropped in your computer due to buffers being full.

Comment: What packet rate?  Do you have interrupt coalescing enabled?

Comment: @Steve-o packet rate is around 2600/s

Comment: @Damon Thank you for your helpful information

Comment: You should be able to get ~120,000 packets per second with a single core, this sounds like you have some other more serious issues.

Comment: @Steve-o wow Steve, i don't know what to say. For more information, I also tried do nothing but only call async_recv_from immediately after received a buffer, and still experience packet drop (not from the cable). let me post my code now.

Comment: 2600 packets/second is a ridiculously low rate. That's approximately what a typical web browser on a typical home computer with a typcial DSL internet connection receives without wasting a thougth when you download a big file (not counting TCP ACKs). Did you profile whether maybe those memory allocations you do (`get_new_buffer()` and `memory_pool_.free`) are the culprits? It's unlikely, but who knows. Memory management _can_ take considerable time. Also I don't know how `boost::async_receive_from` works, but it _might_ quite possibly spawn a thread...? I would stay away from anything async.

Comment: If performance really matters, I would allocate a fixed size pool of MTU-sized buffers before entering the loop, have one socket per address bound, listen on all with `epoll_wait`, having, say, N=16. Then `recvmmsg` as many packets as `epoll_wait` told you (synchronously!). If each packet contains a full message, push it to a work queue (and signal a worker thread), otherwise keep the buffer until enough are there for a complete message. Do nothing else, continue the loop as soon as you can. Worker thread consumes buffer and returns buffer to a "free list", preferrably lock-free.

Comment: The point is, synchronous receives are not slower than asynchronous ones, but you don't know what's going on inside something like `boost::async_receive`. For example the GNU asio implementation spawns threads to handle requests, which is _not a lightweight operation_. You don't really need async operation if you receive readiness notifications. Synchronous will do as good as you possibly can (because data is already there!). The goal is to always drain what's in the recvbuf as fast as you can, so it never gets full.

Comment: Look at the source here: http://lwn.net/Articles/334532/ -- it allocates a pool of 256 buffers, and simply waits with `poll` (not even epoll!) until "something, anything happens", and then reads "the maximum possible" with `recvmmsg`, receiving on the average 15-16 packets of size 256 at a time (rather small), completely saturating a 100Mibit/s line. That's about 36,700 packets/s at this size -- roughly 15 times of what you're having. Without using anything async or even epoll, without ever doing dynamic allocation or using boost.

Comment: @Damon Thank you very much for your suggestion, I will certainly try it out, and come back to you with the result afterward.

Comment: The NIC doesn't know anything about sockets, and there is no way for you to control the size of the NIC's buffers from the application. There is however a way for you to control the *socket receive buffer,* which is in the kernel, not the NIC, and obviously there is one of those per socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packet loss issue was caused by hardware, including switch, and NIC cards. the packet rate is actually 2500 * 70 /sec because there were 70 udp sockets. Highly recommend a network monitoring tool call Wireshark which provide load of information regarding to your current network traffic.

Regarding to Demon solution, Boost asio under the hook use iocp in window, and epoll in unix.

No buffer size need to adjust as well.